# Prevent service worker from running on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, service-worker

I've got a service worker that I am using for push notifications in chrome and firefox, how can I exclude the service worker from running on Safari since it's causing exceptions. I've tried a couple of different ways of detecting if the user agent is safari, but it was always detecting as false even though it is Safari.

The last detection method I've used is as following:

```
// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { 
return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })
(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && 
safari.pushNotification));

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

// Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var safariWindows = ua.indexOf("safari/") !== -1 && ua.indexOf("windows") 
!== -1 && ua.indexOf("chrom") === -1;


if (!isSafari && !safariWindows) {
 //run service worker
}
```

Comment: Use feature detection, not browser detection: `if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { ... }` (from [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/serviceworker.js))

Comment: I think he's saying service workers are enabled, but he has some weird exception in his app code while the worker is being ran on safari...? Right @NaughtNinja ?

Comment: @SeanNewell Service Workers are not supported at all (yet) by Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers

Comment: @Andreas I am aware that service workers are not supported at all by safari and this is why it's really odd that still passes through if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) check?

Comment: My B - I thought they were. Since they aren't suported and the feature detection check passes, I'd consider that a bug in Safari. I'd report it!

Comment: @Andreas you could post an answer using feature detection, and then maybe try to use service workers and catch the exception if it actually isn't supported. I think a `try{  } catch() { }` is what would be needed if safari is being cray cray.

Comment: They did a partial roll out of workers for a nightly version. May be that is the OP's version?

Comment: ServiceWorker is coming, baby!!